# How get current URL from browser

Tags: java, android

I am writing a system app. I need to know what URLs are currently opened in browser.
My application contains `Service` which determines what app is active in the front.
Also my application contains `IME` (SoftKeyboard) which has access to editable views of the activity of the browser (if my IME is open and active).
Is it possible to get current URL opened in browser(native Browser, Opera, Chrome etc.)? Can I get this URL from `Service` or from `IME`?

Answer (score 0):

I use `inputEditor.fieldName` in `IME`. In SDK 2.3.X I get that attribute equivalent `field_name\http://domain.com?blablabla`. I can parse this string and get current URL `http://domain.com?blablabla`.

But this work right only in SDK 2.3.X and don't work in another SDK. This attribute return `null`. May be there is an analogue that attribute in another SDK?

Any idea about how get current URL from browser from own `IME`?